# html2canvas generates a slightly blurry image

Tags: html2canvas

I'm using the basic html2canvas functionality with a gif image inside of a div.  When I convert the div to canvas the image loses quality slightly.  Is there a fix for this, or some option I should be setting?

```
html2canvas($("#panel-container"), {  
  proxy: "https://html2canvas.appspot.com/query",
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
});

html2canvas();
```

[jsfiddle.net/6MnEu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/6MnEu/1/)